# Visual Studio Code detect errors in stdio.h in FILE recognization

Tags: c, types

I've got some issues in VSCode where the FILE type in C isn't recognized. I use the MinGW library to correct issues with the includePath. But now I've got an error in the line 259 of stdio.h...

[First pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s86kG.png)

and this is what I got when I want to use the FILE type in my code :

[Second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC2ZD.png)

The translation of "variable FILE n'est pas un nom de type" is "FILE variable isn't a type name"

```
#include "token.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Enum type that defines the token type */
typedef enum t_Token
{
    number,
    binary_operator,
    parenthesis
} TokenType;

struct s_Token
{
    TokenType type;
    union
    {
        float number;
        char symbol;
    } value;
};

Token *createTokenFromString(const char *s, int lg)
{
    (void)lg;
    Token *t = malloc(sizeof(Token));
    if (isdigit(*s) || *s == '.')
    {
        t->type = number;
        t->value.number = strtof(s, NULL);
    }
    else if (*s == '(' || *s == ')')
    {
        t->type = parenthesis;
        t->value.symbol = *s;
    }
    else
    {
        t->type = binary_operator;
        t->value.symbol = *s;
    }
    return t;
}

Token *createTokenFromValue(float v)
{
    Token *t = malloc(sizeof(Token));
    t->type = number;
    t->value.number = v;
    return t;
}

void deleteToken(ptrToken *t)
{
    free(*t);
    *t = NULL;
}

bool tokenIsNumber(Token *t)
{
    return t->type == number;
}

bool tokenIsOperator(Token *t)
{
    return t->type == binary_operator;
}

bool tokenIsParenthesis(Token *t)
{
    return t->type == parenthesis;
}

float tokenGetValue(Token *t)
{
    assert(tokenIsNumber(t));
    return t->value.number;
}

char tokenGetOperatorSymbol(Token *t)
{
    assert(tokenIsOperator(t));
    return t->value.symbol;
}

char tokenGetParenthesisSymbol(Token *t)
{
    assert(tokenIsParenthesis(t));
    return t->value.symbol;
}

int tokenGetOperatorPriority(Token *t)
{
    assert(tokenIsOperator(t));
    switch (t->value.symbol)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 1;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 2;
    case '^':
        return 3;
    default:
        return -1;
    }
}

bool tokenOperatorIsLeftAssociative(Token *t)
{
    assert(tokenIsOperator(t));
    switch (t->value.symbol)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return true;
    case '^':
        return false;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

void tokenDump(FILE *f, Token *t)
{
    if (t->type == number)
        fprintf(f, "%f ", t->value.number);
    else
        fprintf(f, "%c ", t->value.symbol);
}
```

There's the code where I use FILE type

and there's the header

```
#ifndef __TOKEN_H__
#define __TOKEN_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/** Opaque definition of type Token and ptrToken*/
typedef struct s_Token Token;
typedef Token *ptrToken;

/** Create a Token from the string designed by s, taking only the lg first chars of the string */
Token *createTokenFromString(const char *s, int lg);

Token *createTokenFromValue(float v);

/** dDlete the give token.
 Free the memory used by the token and set the pointer to NULL.
*/
void deleteToken(ptrToken *t);

/** Test if a token represents a number.
 @param t : the token to test
 @return true if the given token represent a number, else false
 */
bool tokenIsNumber(Token *t);

/** Test if a token represents a binary operator.
 @param t : the token to test
 @return true if the given token represent a binary operator, else false
 @note Currently supported binary operators are +,-,*,/,^.
 */
bool tokenIsOperator(Token *t);

/** Test if a token represents a parenthesis.
 @param t : the token to test
 @return true if the given token represent a '(' or ')', else false
 */
bool tokenIsParenthesis(Token *t);

/** get the value of a number token.
 @param t : the token to examine
 @return the value stored in the token
 @pre tokenIsNumber(t) == true
*/
float tokenGetValue(Token *t);

/** Get the operator symbol of a binary operator token.
 @param t : the token to examine
 @return the operator symbol (@see tokenIsOperator)
 @pre tokenIsOperator(t) == true
 */
char tokenGetOperatorSymbol(Token *t);

/** Get the parenthesis symbol of a  token.
 @param t : the token to examine
 @return the parenthesis symbol
 @pre tokenIsParenthesis(t) == true
 */
char tokenGetParenthesisSymbol(Token *t);

/** Get the priority of a binaray operator token.
 @param t : the token to examine
 @return 1 if operator is + or -, 2 if operator is * or /, 3 if operator is ^.
 @pre tokenIsOperator(t) == true
 @see tokenIsOperator
 */
int tokenGetOperatorPriority(Token *t);

/** Is the operator left associative.
 @param t : the token to examine
 @return true if operator is left associative.
 @pre tokenIsOperator(t) == true
 @see tokenIsOperator
 */
bool tokenOperatorIsLeftAssociative(Token *t);

/** Dump the token to the given file */
void tokenDump(FILE *f, Token *t);
#endif
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: the stdio.h errro is almost certainly caused by code you have before the include. PLease show a complete program in the question, not screen shots

Comment: Do the headings in your VSCode indicate you are working with C++?

Comment: No they indicate I'm working with C

Comment: well that code compiles clean for me. Can we please see the error message you are getting regarding stdio.h